# Starting app from the recent menu doesn't start the main activity

Tags: java, android, twitter

I have 3 activities (MainActivity, TwitterActivity, WebBrowserActivity).
WebBrowserActivity uses for showing web info from twitter.

Manifest:
1.

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

2.

```
   <activity
    android:name=".TwitterActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:launchMode="singleInstance" >

<!-- Used for OAuth callback -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="callback"
        android:scheme="x-bker-oauth-twitter" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3.

```
  <activity android:name=".TwitterWebBrowser" />
```

Starting twitter:

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, TwitterActivity.class);    
  mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

When twitt is posted I close TwitterActivity (using finish(); method) and MainActivity shows. Than I press Home Button and goes to Android, than press home button and press my app icon, and I goes to TwitterActivity, but I need to go to MainActivity. How do this?

It is only on android version 2.3.7 and below.

Comment: Can you add some Java code?

Comment: Have you tried using `startActivityForResult()` when starting the TwitterActivity? I think this should change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest entry for the TwitterActivity, change `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.

I think you are setting `launchMode` because you want to be able to jump out to the Twitter app or web page to authorize the user from TwitterActivity, and then return back to the same instance of your TwitterActivity when done.  In that case, TwitterActivity will be at the top of your task stack, so `singleTop` will tell the system to reuse it.

The problem with `singleInstance` is that it makes the activity the only activity in the task, which probably explains why the recents menu is launching the TwitterActivity.  (more info in [activity element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) docs).

If you really need to use `singleInstance`, you should consider assigning it to its own task and excluding it from recents, for example (use your own name for `taskAffinity`):

```
<activity
  android:name=".TwitterActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  android:taskAffinity="com.example.twitter"
  android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```